# Jaccard distance between strings in Rust

Tags: algorithm, strings, rust, edit-distance

The Jaccard distance between two sets is the size of their intersection divided by the size of their union. For example, the distance between `{1, 2, 3}` and `{2, 3, 4}` is 2 (`{2,3}`) / 4 (`{1,2,3,4}`) = 0.5.

The Jaccard distance can be used for string similarity by slicing a string into word or character n-grams. For example, with 2-character n-grams:

```
"Pear" vs "Peach" 
`{"Pe", "ea", "ar"}` vs `{"Pe", "ea", "ac", "ch"}` = 2/5 = 0.4
```

I've written an implementation in Rust as an attempt to learn something about the language.

```
extern crate unidecode;
use unidecode::unidecode;

use std::collections::HashSet;

fn normalize(s: &str) -> String {
    unidecode(s).to_lowercase()
}

fn shingles(s: String) -> HashSet<String> {
    let mut xs = HashSet::new();
    let it = s.chars();
    let mut pk = it.peekable();

    loop {
        let cur = pk.next();
        let nxt = pk.peek();
        match (cur, nxt) {
            (Some(i), Some(nxt_i)) => {
                xs.insert(format!("{}{}", i, nxt_i));
            }
            _ => { break }
        }
    }
    return xs
}

// Intersection of the sets divided by the size of the union of the
// sets.
fn jaccard_distance(s1: String, s2: String) -> f64 {
    let s1_shingles = shingles(s1);
    let s2_shingles = shingles(s2);
    s1_shingles.len() as f64;
    let inter: HashSet<_> = s1_shingles.intersection(&s2_shingles).collect();
    let union: HashSet<_> = s1_shingles.union(&s2_shingles).collect();
    (inter.len() as f64) / (union.len() as f64)
}

fn comp_and_print(s1: &str, s2: &str) {
    let normal_s1 = normalize(s1);
    let normal_s2 = normalize(s2);
    println!("'{}' vs '{}' ... \t {}", s1, s2,
             jaccard_distance(normal_s1, normal_s2));
}

fn main() {
    comp_and_print("Apple sauce", "Apple Trees");
    comp_and_print("Apple pie", "Grandma's Apple pie");
    comp_and_print("Pear", "Peach");
}
```

The shingles method seems particularly bad. I'd like it to be more flexible (for 3 or 4 character n-grams, for instance) and the use of `format!` rather than `join` on a collection like I'd do in Ruby is ugly.

**edit**

Here's Ruby code for `shingles` since I can express what I mean easier in Ruby. My Rust implementation only handles n = 2 because I had trouble figuring out how to make it dynamic.

```
def shingles(str, n = 2)
  (0..(str.length - n)).map { |idx| str[idx..idx+(n-1)] }.to_set
end
```

Comment: For the record, a "2-character ngram" is called a bigram.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I wrote it that way because it also makes sense to use  ngrams on longer length, but good point.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to point out that, say, Googling "2-character ngram" is going to get you a lot of results for ngrams in general, not bigrams. At least, as far as I know. I haven't tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by removing unused code, <s>the whole `normalize` function and</s> the line `s1_shingles.len() as f64`.

Then, in order to actually be able to call your functions easily, we change all `String` arguments into `&str`. You usually want to accept `&str` as more types can provide it. In this case, string literals are the big example.

Let's do `shingles` in a big bang!

```
fn shingles(s: &str) -> HashSet<String> {
    let chars: Vec<_> = s.chars().collect();
    chars.windows(2).map(|w| w.iter().cloned().collect()).collect()
}
```

We start by getting all the characters once into a vector. Now that we have a slice (through the Vec), we can use [`windows`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows), which gives overlapping views into the slice. We then convert each window into an iterator of `char` using `cloned` and then into a string using `collect`. We convert  the overall iterator into a `HashSet`, also using `collect`. Look at that type inference go!

Note that now we have a parameter to `windows` that allows you to extend to arbitrary-sized n-grams!

The other optimization is to avoid collecting into a collection if we just want the count of elements:

```
let inter = s1_shingles.intersection(&s2_shingles).count();
let union = s1_shingles.union(&s2_shingles).count();
```

All together, it now looks like:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn shingles(s: &str) -> HashSet<String> {
    let chars: Vec<_> = s.chars().collect();
    chars.windows(2).map(|w| w.iter().cloned().collect()).collect()
}

fn jaccard_distance(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> f64 {
    let s1_shingles = shingles(s1);
    let s2_shingles = shingles(s2);
    let inter = s1_shingles.intersection(&s2_shingles).count();
    let union = s1_shingles.union(&s2_shingles).count();
    (inter as f64) / (union as f64)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", jaccard_distance("Pear", "Peach"));
}
```

**Edit**

And of course now I see that if I were to scroll down a bit, I'd see that you do use `normalize`. Oops! You should still accept a `&str`, the only change you need to make is to take a reference to the `String`s:

```
println!("'{}' vs '{}' ... \t {}", s1, s2,
         jaccard_distance(&normal_s1, &normal_s2));
```

Comment: Wow, this is just an incredible answer. Thank you so much. P.S. your version runs 30% faster than mine with `cargo bench` on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

**`shingles`**

`shingles` should be named `pairwise_with_repetitions` as that is what it does. I would implement it by zipping the string with itself minus the first character:

```
s.zip(s.remove_first()) // Pseudocode as I am not proficient in Rust
```

**temp overuse**

I suggest avoiding temporary variables when practical, the printing function could have the function calls inlined.

**Does nothing, right?**

I think that:

```
s1_shingles.len() as f64;
```

Does nothing and should be removed.

Comment: I agree about your second two points. I tried to use `zip` + `skip` (like drop in ruby) but had rust-related troubles. I also want to be able to extend `shingles` to take an argument for how many characters to repeat. I've added ruby code for my ideal `shingles` method - how to write in idiomatic rust?